# obj == null vs null == obj

Tags: java, oop

I have always used to check for null like

```
if(null==obj)
```

When I compiled my code and looked into .class file after decompiling, I could see that my code got changed to

```
if(obj==null)
```

I know in java `null==obj` and `obj==null`doesn't matter. But I'm curious to know why compiler changed it?

Comment: ok I should have said "when I decompiled class file using a decompiler"

Comment: what compiler did you use?

Comment: How do you know it was the compiler and not the decompiler that changed it?

Comment: @maerics, I used at least two open source decompilers and checked it

Comment: Just speculation, but: It's common for optimizers to normalize expressions, and then work with those normalized forms. That makes it easier to optimize them, since you're only looking for one specific pattern (since similar patterns now look like just that pattern). It could be that `obj==null` is just the internal normalized form.

Comment: Also, you can use `javap -c` to look at the bytecode itself, no decompiling needed.

Comment: @yshavit, your speculation could be correct also!!!

Comment: @jatinder bhola, do you mean decomplier?

Comment: It's likely compiled to an `ifnonnull` instruction, so the original order is no longer present in the .class file.

Comment: sorry, yes I meant decompiler.

Comment: Someone voted to close this with reason as "primarily opinion-based". Its good that if they can explain the reason behind it.

Comment: On second look: With the two javacs I tried (Oracle 1.7.0_67 and 1.8.0_45), the opcodes are `aconst_null`, `aload_1`, `if_acmpne ...`. This corresponds to `if (null == obj)`, roughly. It could be that the decompilers are normalizing it, not the compiler -- but that it's a standard-enough expression that they all normalize it the same.

Comment: @Bubletan On the two javac I tried, `if (obj == null)` was indeed compiled to `ifnonnull`, but `if (null == obj)` was not. Go figure!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler did not change anything. It faithfully compiled `if (null == obj)` and `if (obj == null)` into different bytecodes, which decompilers converted back to the same Java code.

Comparison with `null` on the right, i.e.

```
if (o == null) {
    ...
}
```

gets translated to this byte code with `ifnonnull` instruction:

```
0: aload_0
1: ifnonnull     ...
```

Comparison with `null` on the left, i.e.

```
if (null == o) {
    ...
}
```

gets translated to a different bytecode with `if_acmpne` instruction:

```
0: aconst_null
1: aload_0
2: if_acmpne     ...
```

In theory, decompiler has enough information to figure out which way the arguments are ordered in the source file. However, they produced the same code for both orderings.

Comment: On my javac (Oracle 1.7.0_67), that is not the case. The ops got compiled to `aconst_null`, `aload_1`, `if_acmpne` (the last one being "if not equal"). Ditto with 1.8.0_45. I haven't tried with Java 9.

Comment: @yshavit You are right, the compiler produces two different sets of bytecode, so it's decompiler who mixes things up. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Both are same in Java, as only boolean expressions can be inside an if. This is just a coding style preference by programmer and team agreement how to write.

The `null != a` is an old practice in programming languages like Java, C++ (called as Yoda Conditions).

As it is valid to write if (`a = null`) and accidentally assign null to the a so writing null first is a guard to stop this accident from happening.

Most programmers use `a == null` just because it looks more simpler for human to understand. Probably this might be the reason why compiler/decompiler put them in such order, maybe there is another reason...